# Client-Server how to identify two different methods

Tags: networking, client-server

I am writing a code for Client-Server and there are two possibilities.

The user will request a specific information A to be transmitted.

The user will request a specific information B to be transmitted.

I would like to identify what the client want in my server side and how the client will do that.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Hey you don't need two different ports. You must send two different types of message from client to server. I don't know what protocols you are using. If it is your own protocol on TCP sockets, you can use TLV format (Type, Length, Value). If you use HTTP than you can use two different endpoints for different REST resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know is quite old question but I think what will be a good idea is to use the [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) Design Pattern!

The idea is that you can use a single port and send your request to `Receiver 1`, `Receiver 1` will decide if can handle this request if not, will pass the request to the `Receiver 2`, `Receiver 2` will have to do the same decision and if can handle the request, then will send the response back to the `Sender`.

So we have the following properties:

1. One port is required
2. The `Sender`(or the Client in other words) is only aware of the 1st Receiver.
3. The responsible receiver will return a response directly to the sender/client even if the sender/client is not aware of that specific receiver.
4. Reduced coupling
5. Dynamically manage the request handlers.

Furthermore, at the end of the chain, you can add behavior to indicate something like a `final` response, or a default response if the request send has no responsible class to handle it.

**UML**

[image: Chain of Responsibility]

**Example**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the information, you can always transmit both information through one pipe and then decipher the needed one on the user side

Answer (score 0):

```
string data = // .. data transmitted.
string[] dataSplit = data.Split(SEPARATOR);

// dataSplit[0] is type of information
switch(dataSplit[0]) {
 case 'Name':
   ... 
   break;
 case 'OS':
   ... 
   break;
}
```

Do you understand ?

Comment: Yes; thank you but the information it does't mean that is a String.. And not implies that I can do string slicing on that information